# How do i replace from "&amp;" to "&" and "&ntilde;" to "Ñ"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why `&amp;` is displaying instead of `&` and `&ntilde;` instead of `Ñ` in my page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialysisUnitName").autocomplete({
        source: [{
                'value': '',
                'id': 0
            }, {
                'value': 'Almazan Renal Care Center',
                'id': '459'
            }, {
                'value': 'Anipolo Doctors Hospital',
                'id': '659'
            }, {
                'value': 'Antipolo Doctors Hospital',
                'id': '308'
            }, {
                'value': 'Antipolo Doctors Hospital',
                'id': '657'
            }, {
                'value': 'Antipolo Doctors Hospital',
                'id': '714'
            }, {
                'value': 'National Kidney &amp; Transplant Institute',
                'id': '28'
            }, {
                'value': 'Los Ba&ntilde;os Doctors Hospital And Medical Center Inc.',
                'id': '679'
            }

        ],
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#dialysisUnitId").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting those values from? It looks like an encoding issue when outputting those values to the page - presumably from a database?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - in my databse its saved "&" not "&amp;" what do you mean encoding?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how do i fix this sir?

Comment: We'd need to see the code you have used to get the values from the database and how you add them to the page to help you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan             <s:iterator value="dialysisUnits" status="rowStatus">
                , {'value':'<s:property value="name" />', 'id':'<s:property value="dialysisUnitId" />'}
            </s:iterator>